# C# List Console

Tags: c#, .net, lista, console

Como eu faço para exibir apenas os terceiros valores da lista, no caso o ("500, 900, 2000, 1500, 2000).

E como eu faço esse mesmo processo pra exibir apenas os terceiros valores da lista que tem associado o segundo valor da lista igual a "Mesa retangular".

```
produtos.Add(new Produto(1001, "Cadeira simples", 500));
produtos.Add(new Produto(1002, "Cadeira acolchoada", 900));
produtos.Add(new Produto(1003, "Sofa de três lugares", 2000));
produtos.Add(new Produto(1004, "Mesa retangulares", 1500));
produtos.Add(new Produto(1005, "Mesa retangular", 2000));
```

Comment: `produtos.ForEach( x => Console.WriteLine(x.[terceirocampo]));` onde [terceirocampo] é a propriedade da classe passada como 3 parametro no construtor do produto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma das formas é usando o Linq.

No exemplo abaixo eu usei o [Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb549418%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) para selecionar somente item "mesa reatngular" e o [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.linq.enumerable.select(v=vs.110).aspx) para criar uma lista somente com a propriedade quantidade.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{

    class Produto
    {
        public  Produto(int id, string nome,double quantidade)
        {
            this.id=id;
            this.nome=nome;
            this.quantidade=quantidade;
        }

        public int id {get;set;}
        public string nome {get;set;}
        public double quantidade {get;set;}

    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Produto> produtos =new List<Produto>();
        produtos.Add(new Produto(1001, "Cadeira simples", 500));
        produtos.Add(new Produto(1002, "Cadeira acolchoada", 900));
        produtos.Add(new Produto(1003, "Sofa de três lugares", 2000));
        produtos.Add(new Produto(1004, "Mesa retangulares", 1500));
        produtos.Add(new Produto(1005, "Mesa retangular", 2000));

        var quantidades = produtos.Where(w=>w.nome=="Mesa retangular").Select(s=>s.quantidade);
        foreach (double qtd in quantidades)
            Console.WriteLine("Quantidade : {0}",qtd);


    }
}
```

Veja funcionado no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CZbOee)

Caso você queria somente criar uma lista com a propriedade quantidade, use o Select, assim:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{

    class Produto
    {
        public  Produto(int id, string nome,double quantidade)
        {
            this.id=id;
            this.nome=nome;
            this.quantidade=quantidade;
        }

        public int id {get;set;}
        public string nome {get;set;}
        public double quantidade {get;set;}

    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Produto> produtos =new List<Produto>();
        produtos.Add(new Produto(1001, "Cadeira simples", 500));
        produtos.Add(new Produto(1002, "Cadeira acolchoada", 900));
        produtos.Add(new Produto(1003, "Sofa de três lugares", 2000));
        produtos.Add(new Produto(1004, "Mesa retangulares", 1500));
        produtos.Add(new Produto(1005, "Mesa retangular", 2000));

        var quantidades = produtos.Select(s=>s.quantidade);

        foreach (double qtd in quantidades)
            Console.WriteLine("Quantidade : {0}",qtd);


    }
}
```

Exemplo no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/K8r9nV)